# Convert data in cookie to JSON object by Jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have set the cookie via php server and send it to frontend page like this

```
$data = array (
    'id' => $graphNode['id'],
    //'birthday' => $graphNode['birthday'],
    'birthday' => '',
    'email' => $graphNode['email'],
    'link' => $graphNode['link'],
    'user_name' => $graphNode['name'],
    'is_logged_in' => 1,
    'profile_pic_link' => json_decode($graphNode['picture'])->url
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
$data = json_encode($data);
setcookie('facebook', $data, time()+3600, "/");
include('http://localhost/trada-frontend/index.html');
redirect('http://localhost/trada-frontend/index.html');
```

In my index.html page, I can alert the cookie

> facebook=%7B%22id%22%3A%221114904728619320%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%22%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22nguyenminhduc183%40yahoo.com%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.facebook.com%5C%2Fapp_scoped_user_id%5C%2F1114904728619320%5C%2F%22%2C%22user_name%22%3A%22%5Cu0110%5Cu1ee9c+Nguy%5Cu1ec5n%22%2C%22is_logged_in%22%3A1%2C%22profile_pic_link%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%5C%2Fv%5C%2Ft1.0-1%5C%2Fp50x50%5C%2F16406482_1104007966375663_2824130433013720008_n.jpg%3Foh%3D0c954d5a8698e78458737741fbf352e6%26oe%3D592DAD80%22%7D

How can I split the name of the cookie and convert the data to JSON object by using jquery? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide some code, at least the content of your cookie (presumably the text inside the alert in the image you provided?)

Comment: It would be useful if you could post the cookie string in your post instead as an image.

Comment: Question shows a serious lack of research effort. This isn't a free code writing service and what you are asking is not hard to research yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery for this: First get the name and content of the cookie via regex, then decode the content and parse it as JSON:

```js
var cookie = 'facebook=%7B%22id%22%3A%221114904728619320%22%2C%22birthday%22%3A%22%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22nguyenminhduc183%40yahoo.com%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.facebook.com%5C%2Fapp_scoped_user_id%5C%2F1114904728619320%5C%2F%22%2C%22user_name%22%3A%22%5Cu0110%5Cu1ee9c+Nguy%5Cu1ec5n%22%2C%22is_logged_in%22%3A1%2C%22profile_pic_link%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fscontent.xx.fbcdn.net%5C%2Fv%5C%2Ft1.0-1%5C%2Fp50x50%5C%2F16406482_1104007966375663_2824130433013720008_n.jpg%3Foh%3D0c954d5a8698e78458737741fbf352e6%26oe%3D592DAD80%22%7D';
var cookieParts = cookie.match(/^([^=]+)=(.*)$/);

console.log("cookie name is " + cookieParts[1]);
console.log("cookie content as JSON is ", JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(cookieParts[2])));
```

Comment: sorry for the picture :( I have edited the question. I will try your solution now. Thank you for your answer

Comment: updated the answer to contain your whole cookie content

Comment: Thank you very much I will try it now

Comment: What "rest parts"? This does exactly what you have been asking for?

Comment: yes it is, I do not see your next comment. Thank you for your patient

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this answer but here is a one liner (using es6+):

```js
var cookie = "referer=example.com/post?id=22;bcomID=8075; subreturn=example&fuzzy=true&ct=null&autobounce=true; JSESSIONID=6D20570E1EB; mbox=session"
var cookies = cookie.split(/[;] */).reduce((result, s)=>
               ({...({[s.split('=')[0]]:s.split('=')[1]}),...result}),
             {});
  console.log(JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 4));
```